# Using xslt, how to add an xml node that starts before the first occurrence, and ends after the last occurrence of an item?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml that looks like this:

```
<ShoppingList>
    <MoneyIHaveToSpend>20.00</MoneyIHaveToSpend>
    <Item>
        <Name>Apples</Name>
        <Price>1.00</Price>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>Oranges</Name>
        <Price>1.00</Price>
    </Item>
    <AdditionalInfo>...</AdditionalInfo>
</ShoppingList>
```

I would like to wrap the "items" into a GroceryList, like so:

```
<ShoppingList>
    <MoneyIHaveToSpend>20.00</MoneyIHaveToSpend>
    <GroceryList>
        <Item>
            <Name>Apples</Name>
            <Price>1.00</Price>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Name>Oranges</Name>
            <Price>1.00</Price>
        </Item>
    </GroceryList>
    <AdditionalInfo>...</AdditionalInfo>
</ShoppingList>
```

There is only one sub-list inside of "ShoppingList". How would I go about doing this using xslt?

I tried to do something like the following, but splitting up `<GroceryList>` and `</GroceryList>` gives me compile errors. I realize that the rest of this is wrong anyway, but I can't even test it or mess around with it because of the compile error:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ShoppingList">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/ShoppingList/Item"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <GroceryList> <!-- Error: "XML element is not closed" -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="???">
        </GroceryList> <!-- Error: "No open tag found" -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XSLT has to be well-formed XML, so you can't start an element in one `xsl:if` and close it in another.

Like C. M. Sperberg-McQueen suggested, start with an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and override from there.

Example (if the order of the `ShoppingList` children doesn't matter):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ShoppingList">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::Item)]"/>
            <GroceryList>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/>
            </GroceryList>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the order does matter, you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item[1]">
        <GroceryList>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::Item" mode="keep"/>
        </GroceryList>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item" mode="keep">
        <!--You could overwrite identity transform here.-->
        <xsl:call-template name="ident"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above is pretty generic but could be simplified if you always know what children `ShoppingList` will have or if you don't need to modify any of the elements. (You could use `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:apply-templates`.)

Answer (score 1):

One other solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="ShoppingList">

        <ShoppingList>
            <xsl:variable name="firstItemName"><xsl:value-of select="./Item/Name/text()"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="firstItem"><xsl:value-of select="$firstItemName"/></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ShoppingList>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <xsl:param name="firstItem"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./Name/text()=$firstItem">
                <xsl:element name="GroceryList">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="../Item"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MoneyIHaveToSpend|AdditionalInfo|text()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I haven't tried running this yet, but I don't think it would work as an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet. In 2.0, the `select` in `xsl:value-of` returns all items of a sequence. In 1.0, it only returns the first. So if you use `<xsl:variable name="firstItemName"><xsl:value-of select="./Item/Name/text()"/></xsl:variable>`, the variable would actually have two items: `Apples` and `Oranges`. In 1.0 you would just have `Apples`. This stylesheet might work if you changed the version to 1.0, but I think you'd still have an extra `Oranges` item output.

Comment: Also, when you use `xsl:variable` (or `xsl:param`, `xsl:attribute`, etc) try to use a `select` attribute instead. If you don't, you create an RTF (result tree fragment) when it's not needed. Here's an example of your `firstItemName` rewritten: `<xsl:variable name="firstItemName" select="./Item/Name/text()"/>`

Comment: @DanielHaley - Thanks for the pointers! I did test it in 1.0 and it's OK, but you make some very good points.

Answer (score 1):

Nodes don't "start" and "end", they are points in a tree with parents and children. You're trying to write XSLT as if it's outputting start and end tags as separable operations, rather than constructing a tree of nodes. Nodes on a tree are indivisible.

If your grouping problem is as simple as the example suggests, then the simplest solution will use a template like:

```
<xsl:template match="ShoppingList">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="MoneyIHaveToSpend"/>
  <GroceryList>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/>
  </GroceryList>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="AdditionalInfo"/>
</xsl:template>
```

When you read this, don't think of `<GroceryList>` and `</GroceryList>` as separate instructions. The template body contains a sequence of three instructions: apply-templates, GroceryList, and apply-templates, and the GroceryList instruction has content (a "sequence constructor") containing instructions to generate the content of the GroceryList node.